# Azure Logic Apps - Azure Text Analyzer error 502 bad gateway

Tags: azure

Im trying to connect Logical Apps with Text Analyzer however i'm seeing this error:

This is the body of the Output:

```
{ "error": { "code": 502, "message": "The remote name could not be resolved: 'supportticket.cognitiveservices.azure.com'", "source": "logic-apis-northeurope.azure-apim.net", "path": "forward-request", "clientRequestId": "343d9512-c398-4544-a3ec-bbdd26ad22bf" } }
```

Not sure how to fix it, seems like its on azure end.
Contacted Azure chat support they forwarded me here for a resolution

Comment: If I do a nslookup on 'supportticket.cognitiveservices.azure.com' I also get "Non-existent domain". So are you sure you have created a cognitive services resource under that name?

Comment: Im quiet sure, here is the overview information of the cognitive service:

Resource group(change)
:
MyResourceGroup
Status
:
Active
Location
:
North Europe
Subscription(change)
:
Free Trial
Subscription ID
:
78abd89b-c039-46e4-8f11-f1096c4b931b
API type
:
Text Analytics
Pricing tier
:
Free
Endpoint
:
https://supportticket.cognitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v2.1
Manage keys
:
Show access keys ...
Tags(change)

Comment: Well now the address seems to work - at least for me. Have you tried your logic app again?

Comment: It does seem to work now, it might be something stuck in Azure. I haven't touched it since this post.